# 301 redirect for old Ajax permalinks

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

My clients old site was running through [Wix](https://www.wix.com).

[Wix](https://www.wix.com) creates AJAX permalinks like this: **old-domain.com/#!about/c20r9** instead of this: **old-domain.com/about**

I have developed a new WordPress site for them via new-domain.com. old-domain.com has been added to new-domain.com as a domain alias.

I would like to re-direct old page urls from old-domain.com to specific pages on new-domain.com. For example:  **old-domain.com/#!about/c20r9** should re-direct to: **new-domain.com/about**.

I understand that 301 redirect rules do not work as the server will not recognise hash urls.

How can I re-direct the old URLs for old-domain.com to new-domain.com?

Comment: Those “weird” links use what called the “hashbang” syntax, and it is mainly intended for sites that load content via AJAX. // Since the hash part of the URL is not even send to the server, you can not redirect based on the hash on the server-side. If you need this, you need to do it client-side via JavaScript.

Comment: _“Is this not working because because the 301 redirect rules are sitting on new-domain.com?”_ – plus that as well, of course. If you want to redirect requests that go to the old domain, that requires you to have access to the old domain to configure rewriting there in the first place.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification on the AJAX. The nameservers for old-domain.com are pointing towards my host. The domain has then been added to new-domain.com as an alias. I assume from what you say, I'd need to create a separate hosting area for old-domain.com with it's own .htaccess file?

Comment: No, not necessarily – if you have both domains pointing to the same webspace, you can still do rewriting based on the requested domain (using mod_rewrite, and a `RewriteCond` to check the host name.) But this doesn’t change the mentioned fact that the hash part of the URL does not get send to the server – so you can not do a server-side redirect based on it, because your server will never get to see it in the first place.

Comment: Thank you, I have updated the question based on your answers. As the hash part of the URL does not get sent to the server, would I need to find a JavaScript solution?

Comment: @Squideyes - yes, you would need a JavaScript solution to solve this. You would need to compile an array of pages to redirect, get the hash from `window.location.hash` (remember to trim out the `#`), match that hash to the one in the array, and redirect to the new URI with `window.location.href = <newUri>`. (Alternatively, if your new page names *always* match the WIX ones, you can simply use a regular expression to pull that out of the old hash so you can do the redirect.)

Comment: That's very useful, thank you. Please feel free to add this as an answer. I have updated my question to reflect everyones comments. Hopefully this is useful for anyone that stumbles across the same challenge.

Comment: You're most welcome. I have added my answer, with code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment, JavaScript is the way to go as the fragment (`#...`) is never sent to the server.

In your specific case, you could use the following JS code to redirect your page accordingly.

**Automatic mode:** Use if the page names have not changed:

```js
// Get the current hash
var currentHash = window.location.hash;

// If there is one, and it is in fact a hashbang, redirect it to the new URI.
// This extracts the 'about' from '#!about/c20r9', for example, and assigns the
// location (/about) once extracted.
if (currentHash.indexOf('#!') == 0){
    window.location.assign(currentHash.replace(/^#!([^\/]+)\/.*/, '$1'));
}
```

**Manual mode:** Use if your page names differ (when comparing Wix to your migrated site). This method maps the redirects using an object, scans the object, and redirects if a match is found.

```js
// Get the current hash
var currentHash = window.location.hash;

// If there is one, and it is in fact a hashbang, redirect it to the new URI,
// based on the array set out.
if (currentHash.indexOf('#!') == 0) {

    // Get the old page name from the hash
    var oldPageHash = currentHash.replace(/^#!([^\/]+)\/.*/, '$1');

    // Define the redirects (old and new counterparts)
    var redirects = {
        'foo-page': 'new-foo-page',
        'bar-page': 'new-bar-page',
    }

    // Loop through the redirects and set the location if there is a match
    for (var oldPage in redirects) {
        if (redirects.hasOwnProperty(oldPage)) {
            if (oldPage == oldPageHash) {
                window.location.assign(redirects[oldPage]);
            }
        }
    }

}
```